# Getting compile error when i try to access firebase data using esp32 code

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am trying to read the firebase data using esp32, when i try to read firebase data statically(string literal) no error is coming.
eg:

```
String board=Firebase.getString(fbdo, F("Device/board")) ? String(fbdo.to<String>()).c_str() : fbdo.errorReason().c_str(); //getting data successfully
```

But when i try to read data dynamically using String object, i am getting compile error for given code

```
  String string2 = "Device/board";
  String board1=Firebase.get(fbdo, F(string2)) ? String(fbdo.to<String>()).c_str() : fbdo.errorReason().c_str(); 

ERROR :   #define F(string_literal) (FPSTR(PSTR(string_literal)))
```

Please give me suggestion to solve this problem

Comment: Hi Ramesh, welcome to SO. In future posts please format your posts to be more readable by adding the code tags (\```) around code listings.

Comment: copy on Arduino SE (with a good answer) https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/90879/compile-error-getting-when-i-try-to-read-firebase-data-using-esp32-in-arduino-id#comment208510_90879